# Is it be possible to get the redesigned Gmail on business accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I have a Google account which is provided by my school. The new (redesigned) version Gmail has many useful features, such as being able to snooze emails and a better user interface for performing actions I take very frequently.

Is there a way to enable the new redesign for business accounts, such as mine? I did not find the same button to enable it in the settings dropdown menu as I did with my personal account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, but you should be patient as the G Suite admin of each organization should migrate their users or to wait until it's generally available.

From [New Gmail now generally available](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/07/new-gmail-ga.html)

> **Options for moving your users to the new Gmail**
>
> As a G Suite admin, you can migrate your users to the new Gmail at a
>   pace that makes sense for your organization. Starting now, the
>   following options are available in the Admin console:

(Follow the above link to learn the available options)